# Python 3 Jupyter Notebook "if" statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create an "if" statement. But it comes back with an error. I have tried the same statement in pycharm and it works.

I use jupyter notebook so that it tells my any errors every line. I don't know what I'm doing wrong please help.

```
staffid1 = input('Input your Staff id here ...')
staffid2 = input('Re-enter your staff id here to confirm...')
if staffid1 == staffid2:
    print('correct, searching database')
else:
    print('invalid Staff id')
    print('Error #1')
```

is it something I'm doing.

error-

```
File "<ipython-input-17-76bd76303e16>", line 1
if staffid1 == Staffid2:
                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

thankyou in advance

Comment: Here is an idea: **show the error**.... [see here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You are somehow trying to execute the ``if`` line by itself, with no body to the if statement.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand. Where I have put the print statement there is other code.

Comment: add some body in if statement or use pass if you want empty if

Answer (score 1):

Staffid2 is capitalised in your error, but not in your original code. It shouldn't cause this exact error but hard to know what's going on if there are differences like this.

As written, your initial code runs fine for me in Jupyter.

It would be useful if you post the whole code *exactly* as you are running it in Jupyter to avoid these types of issues if you are still having problems...